# Tensorflow : Regression with 2D input array and a scalar output

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, neural-network

I am a new user of tensorflow and using it for a regression problem. The input to the neural network model is a two-dimensional array (200 rows and 51 columns) with the output with respect to this input is a scalar. The input arrays and corresponding outputs are stored in a dictionary, for which I am trying to minimize the mean squared error loss. The model is built using the following code

```
keysD = TrainingDic.keys()
loss = tf.zeros([1])
for i in range(len(keysD)):
    X_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [200,51]) 
    trueY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    predY, cost = build_model(X_data,trueY) # neural network returning predicted value and squared error
    loss = tf.add(loss,cost)

meanLoss = tf.divide(loss,len(keysD)) 
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(meanLoss)
```

To run the model

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in range(len(keysD)):
            xTT = TrainingDic[i][0] #array of dimension [200,51]
            yTT = TrainingDic[i][1] #scalar
            feed_dict = {X_data:xTT, trueEnergy:yTT}
            lo = sess.run([meanLoss],feed_dict)
            print(lo)
```

But this gives me the following error

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [200,63]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[200,63], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Will really appreciate if someone can help me with this? I am sure that I am missing a fundamental concept regarding placeholders and will appreciate if guided in the right direction.

Other approach I worked on was to flatten the input array into row vector and provide the whole batch of training dictionary as one. That approach worked without error. the only issue is that I am also seeking gradients of the output with respect to X_data's columns. With the flattened array, I am not sure how to obtain the gradient information.

## Neural network

```
def build_model(X_data,trueY, input_dim):

n_hUnits_1 =20
n_hUnits_2 = 20
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([input_dim,n_hUnits_1], -1,1))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hUnits_1]))
W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_hUnits_1,n_hUnits_2], -1,1))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hUnits_2]))
W_O = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_hUnits_2,1], -1,1))
b_O = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X_data,W_1), b_1)
layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)
# layer 1 multiplying and adding bias then activation function
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1,W_2), b_2)
layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)
# layer 2 multiplying and adding bias then activation function
predY = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2,W_O), b_O)
cost = tf.square(predY-trueY)
return predY, cost
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is a placeholder value that is not supplied when the session is run.

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder'

`tensor 'Placeholder'` suggest a node of the graph with the name `Placeholder`.

The error is coming from the way you're running your session.

```
feed_dict = {X_data:xTT, trueEnergy:yTT}
```

Your model is expecting `trueY` instead of `trueEnergy`.